# Add click event after mouse up

Tags: javascript, click, event-propagation

I have a draggable element. After dragging, I want to add the click-funtion again.
The click-event should not fire when dragging, but I want to add it when dragging is over.

If I add my click-event again after dragging (line 46) it get's fired immediately

```
clickElemtent(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
```

I don't understand the logic.. Thank you so much!

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
clickElemtent(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function clickElemtent(elmnt) {
    elmnt.onclick = function() {
        alert("click")
    }
}

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {  
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    elmnt.onclick = null;

    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement(e) {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;

    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopPropagation();
        
    clickElemtent(document.getElementById("mydiv"));       ///// ?????
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">click OR drag</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to stop the event propagation?

Comment: I have tried to stop the event propagation. (Edited snipped...) No effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mouseup` and `click` are different events (even though both are caused by the same interaction!), so stopping one doesn't affect the other.

## Event order

(An explanation to [Bujaq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75485397/13561410):)

An event's propagation path is determined before propagation. That means adding/removing `click` listeners in another `click` listener won't have any effect on the current event's path.

However, **different event types *can* affect each other**, even those from the same event source, e.g. a mouse click. Events are run in a fixed order; for mouse events, [`mouseup` runs before `click`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mouseevent-event-order).

Taking the [event loop](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) into consideration: Calls to the event handlers are *queued*, so *tasks* added via [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) will be run later. That is also the reason why 0 ms is enough, too.

That means, adding the `onclick` like that will only have an effect *after* the pending events have been handled.

## Conditional call

You want to only accept `click` events if no dragging occured. That means we need a way to tell if dragging occured.

Dragging has always occured if a `mousemove` event happened after a `mousedown` event.

Since a `click` event is fired even when dragging, we can call the "actual" listener only when no dragging occured:

```js
var clickHandler = function(e) {
  alert("click");
};
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"), clickHandler);

function dragElement(elmnt, clickCallback /*New*/) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  var isDragged = false; // New
  
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }
  
  if (clickCallback) {
    elmnt.onclick = function(e) {
      // Only call if no dragging occured
      if (!isDragged) clickCallback(e);
    };
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    isDragged = false; // No dragging since now
    
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    isDragged = true; // Dragging occured

    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement(e) {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">click OR drag</div>
</div>
```

## Capture and stop

Alternatively to conditionally calling the `click` listener, we can just stop the event from propagating.

We need to stop the event **before it reaches the expected listener**. This can be done in two ways:

- With [capturing listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#usecapture).
- With earlier attached listeners.

Both ways require the use of [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach the listeners, which is the preferred way. The `onevent` properties and especially inline event attributes are generally *discouraged*.

In the end we want to make use of the [event flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow). Example:

```js
const select = document.querySelector("select");
const button = document.querySelector("button");

// Notice order of attachment

button.addEventListener("click", function stopEarly(evt) {
  if (select.value === "early") evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

button.addEventListener("click", () => console.log("Button reached!"));

button.addEventListener("click", function stopInCapture(evt) {
  if (select.value === "capture") evt.stopPropagation();
}, { capture: true });

button.addEventListener("click", function stopEarly(evt) {
  if (select.value === "late") evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, { capture: false /*default*/ });
```

```html
<select>
  <option value=none>No stopping</option>
  <option value=capture>Stop in capture</option>
  <option value=early>Stop early</option>
  <option value=late>Stop late</option>
</select>
<button>Log text</button>
```

If we ensure that the propagation-stopping listener is called before the "intended" listener, we don't have to remove and reattach any listeners at all:

```js
var clickHandler = function(e) {
  alert("click");
};
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"), clickHandler);

function dragElement(elmnt, clickCallback /*New*/) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  var isDragged = false; // New
  
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }
  
  if (clickCallback) {
    elmnt.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      // Stop here if dragging occured
      if (isDragged) e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }, { capture: true });
    elmnt.addEventListener("click", clickCallback);
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    isDragged = false; // No dragging since now
    
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    isDragged = true; // Dragging occured

    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement(e) {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">click OR drag</div>
</div>
```

---

Apart from the three sections above, I want to demonstrate one more thing:

## Event delegation

As seen in the [event flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow), an event goes through multiple phases:

1. The capture phase.
2. The target phase.
3. The bubbling phase.

Events propagate down to and up from their target. That means we can **use a single listener** on an ancestor **for multiple targets**. This is called **event delegation**.

Assuming that only one element can be dragged at once, we can attach a single listener on an ancestor, where we'll stop propagation when applicable.

Under these conditions, we can make elements automatically behave as wished simply by adding a class:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
// Add *click* listener to "click or drag" button
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Initial button");
});

// Adding new draggable buttons is simple:
const button2 = document.createElement("button");
button2.classList.add("draggable"); // For dragging functionality
button2.classList.add("blue-button"); // For styling
button2.addEventListener("click", () => console.log("Button 2!")); // The *click* listener
button2.textContent = "Click or Drag 2";

document.body.append(button2);

(function pageWideDraggable() {
  let target = null;
  let isDragged = false;
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", evt => {
    // Get draggable target and reset "dragging memory"
    target = event.target.closest(".draggable");
    isDragged = false;
  });
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", evt => {
    // If draggable target exists, remember that dragging occured and update target's position
    if (!target) return;

    isDragged = true;
    target.style.top = `${target.offsetTop + evt.movementY}px`;
    target.style.left = `${target.offsetLeft + evt.movementX}px`;
  });
  document.addEventListener("click", evt => {
    // Capture click and stop event when dragging occured
    if (isDragged) evt.stopPropagation();
    target = null;
  }, { capture: true });
})();
```

```css
.draggable {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
.blue-button {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<button class="draggable blue-button">
  click OR drag
</button>
```

**Sidenote**: Notice how the deeper elements don't need to be aware of the capturing. This allows for easy [component-based development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering).

Answer (score 0):

```
 function closeDragElement(e) {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;

    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopPropagation();
        
          ///// ?????
    setTimeout(()=>
      document.getElementById("mydiv").onclick = ()=>alert("click")
      ,100 //or set more milis
    ); 
    return true;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t09758fb/1/
EDIT:
Becouse events like dragend click are combined of keydown, keyup - this is a key problem in Your example.
Hence JavaScript is not multithreaded - You never know which action will be fired from a handler,
*but* setTimeout makes  Your task will probably run after other actions in surrounding code block.

Comment: Thank you, works for me, even with 0 ms. But it's not very elegant, and I still don't understand the logic behind...